# Images of unknown dimensions in web pages

Tags: css, image

What is the best way, preferably without going beyond HTML and CSS, to allocate room on the page for an image whose dimensions are not known until runtime?

Answer (score 0):

The question is pretty generic.

If you don't know the image dimensions in advance then a safe way is to let the image float (to the left or right) of the text.

If the image is going to be placed within a table cell then make sure the cell is expandable (i.e you haven't specified a width and something such as `overflow: hidden`).